# How much time passes relative to the protons inside the LHC?

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, time, estimation, large-hadron-collider

The time depends on the speed of movement. Protons in the LHC move at near-light speed. Therefore, they perceive a different time than the scientist who is observing them. My question is how much time passes relative to the protons while scientists are watching them accelerate and collide?